# Send simple survey via email and text

Tags: .net, email, text, survey

I am looking for different options to send out a simple question (which an end user will answer 1 - 10) via both email and text, from a .NET app. This message will be triggered by a specific event and I also need to collect and store each answer from the end user.

There are lots of options out there, but wanted to know, if anyone had an idea or past experience for the most cost effective way to do this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum; it is intended for *specific* programming questions, not open-ended questions like "What's the best way to do X?", since the "best way" is highly dependent on your context, is not broadly applicable to future visitors, and will lead to people providing opinions.

Comment: sendgrid and twilio

Comment: Thanks @pm100 I had looked at this and associated costs. Probably the best way forward - thanks for confirming.

Comment: @DanielMann ahh,  I remember the good ol days when this was allowed

Comment: Also MailKit will work just fine